# How do i stop Flash from throwing standard errors even if i listen to events?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events, error-handling, download

I use a simple SWF to load a image from a server, let's say the image isn't there, Flash then throws: `Error opening URL 'http://...'`

I catch this error with `imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, infoIOErrorEvent);` and just discard the error since i know it's ok.

Flash however still throws an error to the console. The function is called when the event hits so i still get it, what am i missing here?

How can i stop Flash from throwing the error even when i listen for it?

Comment: Could we see the full code you are currently using? You can block out any URL, if you want.

Comment: What about using the catch block to overwrite the message property on the IOError that's being thrown?

Comment: Never mind - it still pops up. Even setting an error to null causes a message... This problem's pretty tough.

Comment: I don't know actually. It usually won't be a problem but since i use Flash in a embedded software thing, EVERY trace it throws disrupts the embedded device rendering the content.